# guard node IP is european (FR or DE)

Tags: ip-address, guard-node

Why is my guard french or german if my IP is from Singapore? I downloaded the Tor installation file from Singapore but my guard is still french.
Why is it like this? I suppose to get asian circuit.

Answer (score 0):

The geographical location of your guard node is unrelated to your personal geographical location. In other words, the locations of relays in your circuit have nothing to do with your actual location. This is intentional since if clients only were to chose relays near them, then the relays would also know that the user is near them, which would hurt the client's anonymity.